# jQuery - Type data to input box and alert it on the screen

Tags: jquery

How to make a script when put these data to (a single input box), it can change to javascript valable and alert it out ??

**eg1. Input data:**

```
name=Tom
age=18
sex=Male
```

**Alert:**

```
alert ('Name:'+$name+', Age:'+$age+', Sex:'+$sex);  //Name:Tom, Age:18, Sex:Male
```

**eg2. Input data:**

```
name=Mary
age=19
sex=Female
```

**Alert:**

```
alert('Name:'+$name+', Age:'+$age+', Sex:'+$sex);  //Name:Mary, Age:19, Sex: Female
```

Comment: can not understand your question...

Comment: Is it a single `input` box or 3 different? Some HTML code would be helpful.

Comment: Javascript has no `$` before variable names. If you intend to get an ID with jQuery, it should look like `$("name")` instead of `$name`

Comment: I suggest you invest some time learning jQuery or javascript for that matter. Your task is as simple as ABC. You won't even have to dig deep. These are just basics.

Comment: It is in a single input box !

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I am not going to provide you with any code. But here's how you would do it.

1. Create a HTML text inputs for these variables and add an 'id' attributes to them.
2. Them create a HTML button element and associate an 'id' attribute to it also.
3. Now in JavaScript, add a listener to the click event on the button and pass a function that will get the values of the three text inputs (using their ids) and use alert to display them like you want!

See? Simple.

[JQuery - Click Listener](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Comment: It will input data in a single input box ! I know how to use the click function...but I don't know which format is good for javascript to know what data I type .

Comment: Okay So you will be typing this in your single text field? "Mary - 18 - Female" ? something like this? And you want to parse it?

Comment: Type 'name=Mary age=19 sex=Female' to single text field, and jquery split or detect the name and set it to val,just like--> var $name=(~~~input box's Name~~~);alert ('Name:'+$name+');

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code. Edited the script for one input only.
Now if you give input "Name:Jabran Age:25 Sex:male"
You will split this string from the spaces " ".
You can then further split it to get rid of Name: and be left with Jabran

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function alertStuff(){
var stuff = $("#stuff").val();
temp = stuff.split(' ');
var name = temp[0].split(":");
var age = temp[1].split(":");
var sex = temp[2].split(":");
alert('Name:'+name[1]+', Age:'+age[1]+', Sex:'+sex[1]);
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="stuff"/>
<button onClick="alertStuff()">Click for Alert!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I need input data in a single input box ! not 3 input box.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to achieve this:

```
<input type="text" id="name" value="Mary">
<input type="text" id="age" value="19">
<input type="text" id="sex" value="female">
<a href="#" id="alert">Alert</a>
```

And jQuery code as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#alert').on('click', function () {
        alert('Name: ' + $('#name').val() + ' Age: ' + $('#age').val() + ' Sex: ' + $('#sex').val());
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BhFGN/

Comment: The data is type in a single input box not 3!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code modified for one input only.

The trick is in splitting the input string to get what you need.
Use this syntax for input "Name:Jabran Age:25 Sex:Male

and this function

```
function alertStuff(){
var stuff = $("#stuff").val();
temp = stuff.split(' ');  
var name = temp[0].split(":");
var age = temp[1].split(":");
var sex = temp[2].split(":");
alert('Name:'+name[1]+', Age:'+age[1]+', Sex:'+sex[1]); 
}
```